# Applying append on mapcon in Lisp

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp, map-function

> The Lisp function `G` is defined by:
>
> ```
> (defun g (l)
>    (mapcon #'list l))
> ```
>
> What is the result of evaluating the form `(apply #'append (mapcon #'g '(1 2)))`? 
> Justify the answer.

I've seen that `mapcon` works with `nconc` and `cdr`, but the final answer will be `(1 2 2 2)` and I don't know how to properly explain it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's call:

```
(mapcon (lambda (list) (print list) nil) '(1 2))
```

Because the anonymous function returns NIL all the time, the resulting list is NIL; the call prints this:

```
(1 2) 
(2)
```

So in your example, when you call `(mapcon #'g '(1 2))`, `g` will be called first with `(1 2)`, then with `(2)`. Function `g` returns a list, and `mapcon` concatenates them.

What happens can be replicated in the REPL by computing each part explicitly:

```
USER> (mapcon #'list '(1 2))
((1 2) (2))

USER> (mapcon #'list '(2))
((2))

USER> (nconc ** *)
((1 2) (2) (2))
```

Finally, `(apply #'append list-of-lists)` calls `append` with a list of arguments.

The signature of `append` is:

```
append &rest lists => result
```

Which means that if `l1`, `l2` and `l3` are lists, the list that contains all their elements is:

```
(append l1 l2 l3)
```

Here the arguments to `append` are stored in a list, so the way to pass an arbitrary list of arguments to a function is by using `apply`. So that means `(apply #'append lists)` concatenates all the lists in lists, which is why in your case the result is `(1 2 2 2)`.

Note that using `apply` is not recommended when the number of arguments is  arbitrary (possibly large), since `apply` is limited by `CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT`. One other possible way to do it is:

```
(loop for list in lists append list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Main thing to understand here is that

```
(mapcon #'f xs)  =  (apply #'nconc  (maplist #'f xs))
                 =  (loop  for ys on xs  nconc (f ys))
```

so that

```
(g xs)              =
(mapcon #'list xs)  =  (apply #'nconc  (maplist #'list xs))
                    =  (loop  for ys on xs  nconc   (list ys))
                    =  (loop  for ys on xs  append  (list ys))
                    =  (loop  for ys on xs  collect       ys )
                ;;  =  (maplist  #'identity  xs)
```

which is just an iterated application of `#'cdr` to the argument list, collecting its non-empty suffixes:

```
[4]> (loop  for ys on '(1 2)  collect ys)    ; (g '(1 2))
((1 2) (2))

[5]> (loop  for ys on '(  2)  collect ys)    ; (g '(  2))
(      (2))
```

Thus we have

```
(mapcon #'g '(1 2)) 
=
(loop  for ys on '(1 2)  nconc (g ys))
=
(loop  for ys in '((1 2) (2))  nconc (g ys))     ; ----- 'in' NB
=
(nconc  (g '(1 2))  (g '(2)))
=
(append  '((1 2) (2))  '((2)))
=
'(         (1 2) (2)     (2) )
```

and thus

```
(apply #'append (mapcon #'g '(1 2)))
=
(apply #'append (nconc (g '(1 2)) (g '(2))))
=
(apply #'append (append '((1 2) (2)) '((2))))
=
(apply #'append '(        (1 2) (2)    (2) ))
=
(        append          '(1 2)'(2)   '(2)  )
=
'(                         1 2   2      2   )
```